# Как просмотреть diff изменений в индексе?

Tags: git, git-diff

Как в git просмотреть diff локальных изменений, которые еще не закоммичены, но уже добавлены в индекс (с помощью `git add ...`)?

Все еще осложняется тем что репозиторий локальный и нет возможности сделать

```
git diff origin/master
```

А просто `git diff` ничего не выдает. Хотя `git status` показывает, что изменения в файлах есть

Хочу посмотреть что поменлось в файлах, перед тем как их коммитить.

Comment: Видимо, `git add` нужных изменений вы уже сделали?

Comment: @D-side да. И уже давно. Актуализировал файлы с сервера.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте опцию --cached: `git diff --cached`